# how to cygwin tail over c:/wamp/logs/ file in Windows?

Tags: windows, cygwin, wamp, tail

I'm using Cygwin:

```
tail -f prueba.txt
```

The file is located in c:\cygwin\home\ (/home/).

How can I do exactly the same for a file that is located in:

```
c:/wamp/logs/
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cygdrive` is the root point for Windows drives so `c:\` can be found within CygWin at `/cygdrive/c`.

So the command you're looking for is:

```
tail -f /cygdrive/c/wamp/logs/somefile.txt
```

Comment: Maravillosos!! Brilliant!! Thanks!

Comment: i usually use this command in combination with grep to colorize errors , also you can use  tail -f /cygdrive/c/wamp/logs/*